OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError when I try to load a saved Keras FeatureSpace
My code looks something like this
from keras.utils import FeatureSpace

def get_FeatureSpace(dataset: tf.data.Dataset) -> keras.utils.FeatureSpace:
    path = "data/featurespace.keras"
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        reloaded_feature_space = keras.models.load_model(path, compile=True)
        return reloaded_feature_space
    else:
        features = FeatureSpace(
            features={
                "timestamp": FeatureSpace.float_normalized(),
                "distance_from_shore": FeatureSpace.float_normalized(),
                ...
            },
            output_mode="dict",
        )
        features.adapt(dataset)
        features.save(path)
        return features

def train():
    dataset = get_tf_sql_dataset_all_typs(limit_each_class=total_points_per_class) # returns SqlDatasetV2
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_sql_data)
    dataset = dataset.batch(points_per_trip)

    # Get adapted feature Space
    feature_space = get_FeatureSpace(dataset=dataset)
    dataset = dataset.map(feature_space)
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()


When I create and adapt the FeatureSpace, it works as it should. However, when I load the file I get the error
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. You can attempt the following resolutions to the problem: If you are running in Graph mode, use Eager execution mode or decorate this function with @tf.function. If you are using AutoGraph, you can try decorating this function with @tf.function. If that does not work, then you may be using an unsupported feature or your source code may not be visible to AutoGraph. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.


When I try to use get_FeatureSpace with the decorator @tf.function
I get the following error on load
TypeError: To be compatible with tf.function, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors or ExtensionTypes or None values; in compilation of <function get_FeatureSpace at 0x144bd6dc0>, found return value of type FeatureSpace, which is not a Tensor or ExtensionType.

when it first gets created nothing happens in adapt
ChatGPT approaches like tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) do not seem to have any effect as well
